# Delphi - Image move randomly inside desktop coordinates

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to created a small application, which should move images smoothly into the desktop coordinates.
I was wondering how can I limit that the image remains inside the desktop? 
I have try like that to move the image:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
Var
  X, Y :Integer;
begin
  X:= random(2+1);
   Y:= random(2+1);
    Image1.Left:= Image1.Left + X;
     Image1.Top:= Image1.Top + Y;
      Image1.Refresh;
end;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use values for X and Y that when added to Top or Left would move the image too far.

Comment: @KenWhite that is exactly his problem, he wants to detect WHEN he goes outside... either the window or the desktop

Comment: @Arioch'The: Yes, and I told him just how to do so - after generating X and Y values, make sure before adding to Top or Left that doing so will not cause the image to go outside.

Comment: @KenWhite it is like wise owl suggests mice to became hedgehogs when they complain about being eaten by cats. And when mice asked how to become hedgehogs, the wise owl says he solves strategic problems, not tactical ones. His problem is EXACTLY that the image is going to far outside the boundaries, and you suggest him to stop moving his image too far he should stop moving the image too far. Well, that is absolutely correct advice of course....

Comment: @Arioch'The: No, I told him **how** to stop moving the image too far. *Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.* I prefer to teach rather than hand out fish when possible.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. If you actually mean the *Windows desktop boundaries*, post the code where you're actually displaying the image on the desktop. If you mean your *window boundaries*, [edit] your question and ask that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is you image placed over Windows Desktop - or over you `TForm1` ? I guess the latter. So you would have to care about the WINDOW size, not the DESKTOP size.

```
type TForm1=class(TForm)
....
private
   ImageMovesLeft, ImageMovesUp: Boolean;
end;

.....

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
Var
  dX, dY, NewLeft, NewTop :Integer;
  FormSize: TRect;
begin
  dX := random(2+1); // did you really mean "random(3)" or "1+random(2)" ???
  dY := random(2+1);

  FormSize := Self.ClientRect;
  FormSize.Bottom := FormSize.Bottom - Image1.Height - 1;
  FormSize.Right  := FormSize.Right  - Image1.Width - 1;

  // now we have the "box" in which the Image's topleft corner must be

  If ImageMovesLeft then dX := -dX;
  If ImageMovesUp   then dY := -dY;

  NewLeft := Image1.Left + dX;
  NewTop  := Image1.Top + dY;

  if ( NewTop >= FormSize.Top ) and ( NewTop <= FormSize.Bottom ) then begin
     Image1.Top := NewTop; // we fit into the allowed box
  end else begin
     ImageMovesUp := not ImageMovesUp; // we did not fit and have to bounce back
  end;

  if ( NewLeft >= FormSize.Left ) and ( NewLeft <= FormSize.Right ) then begin
     Image1.Left := NewLeft; // we fit into the allowed box
  end else begin
     ImageMovesLeft := not ImageMovesLeft; // we did not fit and have to bounce back
  end;

end;
```

PS. In an unlikely case you really do need the Windows DESKTOP coordinates and not your Form coordinates you can get them at

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.DesktopRect

But to use that information you would have to solve another problem - how to place your `Image1` over desktop and not over the form, which is much more complex for you. So I do not think you really meant Desktop....

UPD. The code above if very simple and easy to understand, but it makes few implicit assumptions to work correctly. Those assumptions are:

- The window(form) size is fixed once for all, it would never be resized.
- The imagebox size is fixed once for all, it would never be resized.
- The window is larger than an imagebox in both dimensions.
- Only our procedure can move the imagebox, there is nothing else that can move it.

Given those assumptions ( natural for fixed screen size computers many many years ago ) there is no need to analyze if the moving object got too left o too right, too above or too below. It only matters if the new coordinate is correct or not - if it is no more correct, then "bouncing" - reversing the direction without looking which one it was - is enough. But if, for example, user can suddenly resize the window and make it so small that the imagebox would fall outside of it - then this method would stuck infinitely switching directions, because the coordinates would always be incorrect given those very small changes "smooth" movement allows to have.

To adapt to possible sudden and large changes in geometry there can be a number of approaches, but the most simple one would be to make two changes: distinction between two cases of wrong coordinates (too little or too large now would be different cases) and instant jumps of the image into the allowed box when needed, even if the jump would be large and not-smooth.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  dX, dY, NewLeft, NewTop :Integer;
  FormSize: TRect;
begin
  dX := random(2+1); // did you really mean "random(3)" or "1+random(2)" ???
  dY := random(2+1);

  FormSize := Self.ClientRect;
  FormSize.Bottom := FormSize.Bottom - Image1.Height - 1;
  FormSize.Right  := FormSize.Right  - Image1.Width - 1;

  // now we have the "box" in which the Image's topleft corner must be

  If ImageMovesLeft then dX := -dX;
  If ImageMovesUp   then dY := -dY;

  NewLeft := Image1.Left + dX;
  NewTop  := Image1.Top + dY;

  if NewLeft > FormSize.Right then begin
     ImageMovesLeft := True; 
     NewLeft := FormSize.Right;
  end;
  if NewLeft < FormSize.Left then begin
     ImageMovesLeft := False; 
     NewLeft := FormSize.Left;
  end;

  if NewTop > FormSize.Bottom then begin
     ImageMovesUp := True; 
     NewTop := FormSize.Bottom;
  end;
  if NewTop < FormSize.Top then begin
     ImageMovesUp := False; 
     NewTop := FormSize.Top;
  end;

  Image1.Top := NewTop;
  Image1.Left := NewLeft; 
end;
```

UPD. Several controls moving.

```
type TControlledObject = record
       obj: TControl;
       MovesLeft, MovesUp: Boolean;
end;

type TForm1=class(TForm)
....
private
   images: array of TControlledObject;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(....);
begin
  SetLength(images, 3);

  with images[0] do begin
     obj := Self.Image1;
     MovesLeft := random >= 0.5;
     MovesUp   := random >= 0.5;
  end;
  with images[1] do begin
     obj := Self.Image2;
     MovesLeft := random >= 0.5;
     MovesUp   := random >= 0.5;
  end;
  with images[2] do begin
     obj := Self.Image3;
     MovesLeft := random >= 0.5;
     MovesUp   := random >= 0.5;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer
begin
  for i := 0 to Length(images)-1 do 
    MoveImage(images[i]);
end;

procedure TForm1.MoveImage(var ImgRec: TControlledObject);
var .....
begin 
  dX := random(2+1); // did you really mean "random(3)" or "1+random(2)" ???
  dY := random(2+1);

  FormSize := Self.ClientRect;
  FormSize.Bottom := FormSize.Bottom - ImgRec.obj.Height - 1;
  FormSize.Right  := FormSize.Right  - ImgRec.obj.Width - 1;

  // now we have the "box" in which the Image's topleft corner must be

  If ImgRec.MovesLeft then dX := -dX;
  If ImgRec.MovesUp   then dY := -dY;
```

....and so on. Finish the conversion from one to many as your home task.

Comment: The poster says *over the desktop*, so apparently it's not the window dimensions that are a problem.

Comment: @Ken, yes, I was addressing that. But frankly, Ken, do you think that a person asking just how to move the image inside given bounds - already solved how to make a no-caption no-borders above-all another form to host that mage and float over the desktop? Do you? If so - then there is a link to Desktop's `TRect` and he can use it instead `TForm1.ClientRect;`  - assuming that was his ONLY problem in that endeavour.

Comment: @KenWhite actually he did not say he wanted to move the image "over the desktop", he said "into the desktop coordinates" WHATEVER that might mean. I think he just struggles with English so that part might be ignored.

Comment: The title says *move randomly inside desktop coordinates*, and the body of the question says *move images smoothly into the desktop coordinates* and * the image remains inside the desktop*. Seems pretty clear to me that saying *desktop* in three separate places means the **desktop**.

Comment: @KenWhite I welcome you to express that idea of smooth slightly fizzy moving in his or mine native language and we would see how consistent and coherent your explanation would turn to be. You assume the person speaks Oxford-grade English and words exactly what he wants to express. I think that hypothesis is too strong to hold true. W.r.t. `saying desktop in three separate places means the desktop` it is exactly  the opposite, it only takes ONE mistake of wrong translation choice.

Comment: *I want to teach my cat to fetch. I want to throw a ball and have my cat retrieve it. I want to be able to play fetch with my cat.* - Oh, wait. He must really mean his dog. No, if the individual says **desktop** (and especially when it's repeated three separate times), the **presumption** must be that they actually mean **desktop**.

Comment: Yes he could. It only takes ONE wrong idea about cats and dogs to make a dozen replicated equal mistakes. And "move images into the desktop **coordinates**" just shows how fuzzy his English is.

Comment: I'm not debating this endlessly with you. The poster clearly said *within the desktop coordinates* three separate times, and until the OP edits the post otherwise it means *desktop coordinates*. You can argue as long as you'd like, and it won't change that fact. If you're so uncertain what was intended, post a comment to the poster and ask for clarification.

Comment: @ Arioch 'The , thanks so much.
Your solution is what i have asked.
Thanks

Comment: Guys, maybe I'm expressed badly, but the Arioch 'The code is correct. thanks so much.
Your solution is what i have asked.
Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: @SHKODRAN glad that it helped. If so then please mark the answer as the correct one. There should be green tickle in the left below up/down rating buttons

Comment: @SHKODRAN actually that code has a severe limitation: it assumes window size would not change, so just changing the direction of sliding is enough to keep the image inside. However, if your form might be suddenly resized then if the image would be near right or bottom edge and you suddenly shrink the window to small size - the image would stuck there outside the form. So that simple and easy to understand code fixes your programmatic sliding of the object inside the never changing window. But it does not fix effects of user resizing the window itself.

Comment: @ Arioch 'The , about the windows size , it's not a problem , the form can't resized , it is like a screensaver ,the form is hiden.
if you want , I can post  the source.
I want to ask something else: in case i have more than one image , how i can move them in different positions, always inside the coordinates?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SHKODRAN make array of records, each record would have those two Boolean direction variables and a link to the image. Which Delphi do you use ?

Comment: you should had tagged it because that is determining with language and library features are available to use.

Comment: @Arioch 'The , thanks so much.

Comment: @Arioch 'The , It works properly.
Is there any way to make them move smooth and linear without jumping ?
Thanks.

Comment: They do not jump unless you make huge changes like big resizing